# Converting a String element to a complex type using Codable

Tags: json, swift, codable

## Context

Currently decoding JSON data that contains the following element :

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            ...
            "rrule": "FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR",
            ...
         }
     ]
}
```

I parse the JSON data and collect the value of `rrule` into a String. So far so good, everything works fine.

## Problem

However I would like to convert that `String` into a complex Swift object (enum / struct). Essentially, I am trying to parse that string according to its format, defined in [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.10).

Is it possible to do that using Codable (Encodable, Decodable) ? I understand it's somewhat orthogonal to the parsing of the json data...

## Tentative solution (fail)

A simplified version (limited to decoding FREQ) of the entire structure would look like :

```
public struct ScheduledEventList: Codable {
    public let events: [ScheduledEvent]
}

public struct ScheduledEvent: Codable {
    public let title: String
    public let rrule: RecurrenceSchema? = nil
    
    public init(
        title: String,
        rrule: RecurrenceSchema?,    <---- problem
        ) {
        self.title = title
        self.rrule = rrule
    }
}

public enum RecurrenceFrequency: String, Codable {
    case DAILY
    case WEEKLY
    case MONTHLY
    case YEARLY
}

public enum RecurrenceSchema: Codable {
    
    case FREQ(RecurrenceFrequency)
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case FREQ
    }
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let value = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .FREQ)
        self = .FREQ(RecurrenceFrequency(rawValue: value!)!)
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        switch self {
        case .FREQ(let freq):
            try container.encode(freq.rawValue, forKey: .FREQ)
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that the element returned from the JSON data is (of course) a `String` so it complains about it :

> error: Playground.playground:99:12: error: cannot convert value of
> type 'String' to expected argument type 'RecurrenceSchema?'
> rrule: "FREQ=WEEKLY",
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

Any suggestions ? Or is it better / easier to build the parser outside of the decoding -- and just deal with String in the encoding / decoding logic ?

thanks !

Comment: Decodable is definitely not the way to parse a recurrence rule. If you're curious, I wrote an RRULE parser. See https://github.com/rmaddy/RWMRecurrenceRule

Comment: You will need to supply your own "encoding" and "decoding" paths to customise the way the JSON is read/written.  Start by having a look at [Ultimate Guide to JSON Parsing with Swift 4](https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/) for insperation

Comment: @MadProgrammer, thanks for the pointer to the parsing guide. Very helpful. I was able to define the `ScheduledEvent` in terms of `RecurrenceSchema` as such : `let rrule = try container.decode(RecurrenceSchema.self, forKey: .rrule)`. However that's about as far as it goes and then I need to use a parser to extract each member of the value of the RRULE.

Comment: @rmaddy, looks like `RWMRuleParser` might be able to do the trick with `parse(rule:)` and `rule(from:)`. Is the install not available through Carthage though ?

Comment: I have no idea what Carthage is so I guess not. :)

Comment: No worries. Thanks. FYI : https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage

Answer (score 0):

So after looking at the different suggestions, and going down my own rathole of trying to make `Codable` work, I have actually settled on using an initializer for my recurrence rule, based on the provided recurrence string.

The string is still parsed from JSON via Codable, but that's where I stop. The "inner" parsing of the rule is done using `'String.split(separator:)`. Then some map / reduce operations are used to feed all the tokens to a Dictionary -- which is then used to construct the recurrence rule object. Early **rough** draft below :

```
public struct RecurrenceRule {
    public let frequency: RecurrenceFrequency
    public let durationUntil: Date?
    public let durationCount: Int?
    public let interval: Int?
    public let byDay: [RecurrenceByDay]?
    public let byMonthDay: [RecurrenceByMonthDay]?
    public let byYearDay: [RecurrenceByYearDay]?
    public let byWeekNo: [RecurrenceByWeekNo]?
    public let byMonth: [Int]?
    public let bySetPos: [RecurrenceByYearDay]?

    public init(rule: String) {
        let splitResult = rule
            .split(separator: RecurrenceRuleSeparation.semicolon.rawValue)
            .map { $0.split(separator: RecurrenceRuleSeparation.equal.rawValue)}
            .map { (RecurrenceKeyword(rawValue: String($0.first!)), $0.last!) }
            .reduce([RecurrenceKeyword: String]()) { result, interm in
                var resultCopy = result
                resultCopy[interm.0!] = String(interm.1)
                return resultCopy
            }
        self.frequency = RecurrenceFrequency(rawValue: splitResult[RecurrenceKeyword.FREQ]!)!
        [....]
    }
}
```

There's probably better / easier ways to achieve this, but that's what I have at this point.